# How to parse XML data with colon

Tags: xml

Following is my XML feed

```
<PostalAddress>
    <datatype:city>DummyCity</datatype:city>
    <datatype:country>DummyCountry</datatype:country>
    <datatype:line1>DummLine1</datatype:line1>
    <datatype:line2>DummyLine</datatype:line2>
</PostalAddress>
```

And following is the code used to read and generate PDF

```
<fo:table-row>
    <fo:table-cell background-color="#FFFFFF">
        <fo:block text-align="left" font-size="8pt" padding-bottom="5px">
            <xsl:value-of select="//PostalAddress/datatype:city"/>
        </fo:block>
    </fo:table-cell>
</fo:table-row>
```

The PDF is generated but fails to load. My objective is to print values of PostalAddress elements line by line.

Comment: Are you just trying to generating table rows without anything else, or aren't you showing all of the code?

Comment: @ocrdu not showing all of it. Looking for a way to solve the issue with this if possible.